# while dynamic button creation take long time to create button

Tags: android

[My screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hex4e.png)
my code

```
private void addItem(int i) {
        if(pagination==0) {
            pagination=1;
            buttonList.clear();
            // Create dyamic page button
            int size = (int) Math.ceil(totcheckCount * 1.0 / rowSize);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                final int page_postion;
                page_postion = j;
                final Button btnPage = new Button(getActivity());

                lp.setMargins(5,0,5,0);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                btnPage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                //btnPage.setTextSize(20.0f);
                btnPage.setId(j);
                btnPage.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.cmn_btn_style );
                btnPage.setText(String.valueOf(j + 1));
                if(j==0){
                    btnPage.getId();
                    btnPage.setTextColor( Color.RED );
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                            .setActionBarTitle( getActivity().getString( R.string.manage_position) + " " + 1 );
                }
                mLinearScroll = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);
                mLinearScroll.addView(btnPage, lp);
                commonSharedPref.clearAll();
                commonSharedPref.pagination(btnPage.getId(), page_postion);
                btnPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        /**
                         * add arraylist item into list
                         */
                        toggleDeSelectAll();
                        feedBackModelList.clear();
                        Button btn_index = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(0);
                        btn_index.setTextColor( Color.WHITE);
                        int page=Integer.valueOf( btnPage.getText().toString() );
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                                .setActionBarTitle(getActivity().getString( R.string.manage_position)+" "+page);
                        int limit=(page-1)*20;
                        if (ApiConstants.isNetworkAvailable( getActivity() )) {
                            Button b = (Button)v;
                            buttonList.add( String.valueOf( b.getId()  ));
                            buttonList.size();
                            if(buttonList.size()>1){
                                int btn_id=Integer.valueOf( buttonList.get( 0 ) );
                                b=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(btn_id);
                                b.setTextColor( Color.WHITE );
                                buttonList.remove( 0 );
                            }
                            getFeedback( limit, page_postion );
                            btnPage.setTextColor( Color.RED );
                        }else{
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(feedbackpage, R.string.check_network, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                        commonSharedPref.clearAll();
                        commonSharedPref.pagination(limit, page_postion);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        //set view
        setView();
    }
```

**The Error Logcat...**

> 06-23 06:20:08.221 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x008e
>   06-23 06:20:09.481 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4418K, 47% free 23107K/43292K, paused 6ms, total 7ms
>   06-23 06:20:11.231 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1958K, 47% free 23181K/43292K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   06-23 06:20:13.011 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1956K, 47% free 23257K/43292K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   06-23 06:20:14.901 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1958K, 47% free 23333K/43292K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   06-23 06:20:16.591 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1961K, 46% free 23410K/43292K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>   06-23 06:20:18.361 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1962K, 46% free 23486K/43292K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>   06-23 06:20:20.071 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1961K, 46% free 23562K/43292K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   06-23 06:20:21.841 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1962K, 46% free 23639K/43292K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
>   06-23 06:20:23.521 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1962K, 46% free 23715K/43292K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   06-23 06:20:24.511 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 46% free 23743K/43292K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
>   06-23 06:20:24.511 26464-26464/com.organizer.infinijith.organizer

Comment: Where do you call the ```addItem``` and what's the value of ```size```.

Comment: i got size from api.

Comment: Can you post the code of the method where you call the ```addItem``` method.

Comment: this is for pagination with button for example i have 5000 records.               int size = (int) Math.ceil(5000 * 1.0 / 20);

Comment: And you create 5000 buttons ????

Comment: int size = (int) Math.ceil(5000 * 1.0 / 20);    250 buttons

Comment: Ok so you create 250 buttons...not one...that should take time and it's not ok, you should try to use a ListView or something like that, or create a reuse mechanism for your buttons, or else you'll have performance issues.

Comment: FSM save us! for such things you should use RecyclerView/ListView ... if it would be well implemented then, if you already have list of 5000 POJOs,  you can even show it without pagination(of course showing so many elements can be disputed, but still performance should be good)

Comment: k thanks i will try.

Comment: i have added my screen.

Comment: @ArulKumar check this link hope it will help you https://rakhi577.wordpress.com/tag/android-listview-pagination/

Comment: thanks mates great...